# Trying to return list of values at even positions in current list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

The goal here is to pass a list to the function and have it return a list with the values at the even positions in that previous list.

eg. return-evens '(1 2 3) => (2) , return-evens '() => ()

I've finally created this function, however it is only working when I enter 0-3 values. And when I enter 0 or 1 values, instead of returning "()", it just returns "NIL".

How can I get this to work with more than 3 values, and how can I return it so that it prints it out as a list, with parentheses surrounding it?

```
(defun return-evens (lst)
    (let ((return-list ()) (i 1))
    (loop for x in lst
        while (numberp x)
            do (if (= (mod i 2) 0)
                    (setf return-list (append return-list x))
                    ()
                    )
            do (setq i (1+ i))
            finally (return  return-list))))
```

Comment: An easy solution would be `(loop for x in (cdr lst) by #'cddr collecting x)`.

Comment: That works great! Thanks!

Comment: One possible problem here is, well, you might be surprised by: (position 1 '(1 2 3)) I do not mean this as a quibble: if this is for someone else they might be thinking the same way.

Comment: `Nil` is the same thing as `()`.  http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_acc.htm : `nil` might be printed as `()` when `*print-pretty*` is true and _printer escaping_ is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Some feedback to your code.

First big problem: **it is not properly indented**.

```
(defun return-evens (lst)          ; in Lisp you can call it list instead of lst
                                   ; return is not a useful prefix.
                                   ; Every function returns something

    (let ((return-list ()) (i 1))  ; LOOP can return lists and iterate.
                                   ; No need for this at all.

    (loop for x in lst

        while (numberp x)   ; why this test? Are there non-numbers in the list?

            do (if (= (mod i 2) 0)   ; Lisp has a function EVENP
                                     ; but generally it is not necessary

                    (setf return-list (append return-list x))
                            ; never append to the end. Never ever.
                            ; Let LOOP collect a list, don't do it this way

                    ()
                    )

            do (setq i (1+ i))  ; iterating manually is not necessary
                                ; that's what LOOP is for

            finally (return  return-list))))
                    ; if you would let LOOP do the work, no RETURN necessary
```

A much simpler solution:

```
(defun elements-at-even-positions (list)
  (loop for element in list
        for even-position = nil then (not even-position)
        when even-position collect element))
```

Comment: Or `(loop :for element :in (rest list) :by #'cddr :collect element)`.